# Reusing container and container extending other containers

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { setLocation } from 'redux/modules/filters'
import SearchForm from 'components/SearchForm/SearchForm'

type Props = {
};

export class HomeSearchContainer extends React.Component {
  props: Props;

  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this)
  }

  onSearch(address, event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (address) {
      this.props.actions.setLocation(address)
    }
    this.context.router.push('/browse_items')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SearchForm
        onSearch={this.onSearch}
        currentLocation={this.props.currentLocation}
      />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentLocation: state.filters.location
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  var actions = {
    setLocation
  }

  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HomeSearchContainer)
```

I have a few questions to validate my understanding.

1. Do we ever re-use containers? Am I correct if I say we intend to re-use components but not containers?
2. In the above code, I want to create another container that doesn't redirect to `/browse_items`. In other words, I just want to override `onSearch` function of this container. Is it okay to extend this container?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in my mind a container is a certain kind of component, so following this article: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.jqwffnfup I'll rather talk about container components and presentational components.

Ad 1) I would say we can re-use container components as well as presentational components - this always depends on how our code is structured. E.g. a container component might have child components, which can be different in different parts of the screen, but the container component is being re-used.

Ad 2) If you just want to have a different `onSearch` functionality, I might consider passing the `onSearch` callback to the `HomeSearchContainer` via the props. That way, you can re-use the same container, but it behaves differently.
Looking closely at your code, there is then not much left to the `HomeSearchContainer`, so you might as well use the `SearchForm` directly. If you need the `SearchForm` in multiple places, it might be worth pulling out the `onSearch` function into its own file and re-using that. But this is hard to judge without seeing the rest of the application. So I'm trying to throw some ideas at you here, which may or may not apply to your codebase.